# R shiny reactable run function only onclick

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt, reactable

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(reactable)

ui <- {
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      div(reactableOutput("atlas_cohort_tbl"),style = "font-size:80%")
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  output$atlas_cohort_tbl <- renderReactable({
    df <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]
    
    reactable(df,selection = "single",
              details = function(index) {
                cat(paste("Ran for ", index, "\n"))
                # run complex algorithm at real time
                paste("Details for row:", index)},
              onClick = c("expand"),
              # Give rows a pointer cursor to indicate that they're clickable
              rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"))
    
    
    
 
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have this simple application with a reactable table. What I want to do is when a row is clicked expand the row with details but run the details only when the row is clicked. Currently the details function runs for all rows prior. I only want to run for the row that is clicked because the table will have over 2000 rows and the detail function is going to be complex and time consuming. I am sure this can be done with JS which I am not too familiar with.

Also I like the row selection of datatable than reactable. You see the entire row highlighted and I can easily pull the row selections.

Can this workflow be done with datatable? Basically click on the row and the row expands with detail which is calculated at realtime using the function.

Comment: Unless the content of the table relies on user input or streamed-in data, you could compute the details for each row ahead of starting the app.

Comment: @Till I do not want to compute the details for all rows ahead of running the app. The details that is to displayed include status of a report which need to be checked if it was already run or not. Between the start of the app and click of the row, the status could be different.

Comment: An easier option would be using observeEvent() with actionButton. But I am trying to avoid adding buttons and I want display the details along with the row. I would rather expand row with the details on click of the row.

Comment: It's strange that the function ran for all rows at the startup. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want. Do you want to use `groupBy`? Do you want to render something generated by your function in the row details?

Does this app answer your question?

```r
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("rtbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dat <- MASS::Cars93[1:5, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]
  
  output[["rtbl"]] <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      dat, 
      groupBy = "Manufacturer",
      onClick = JS("function(rowInfo, column) {
          Shiny.setInputValue('rowClicked', rowInfo.index + 1, { priority: 'event' })
        }"
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["rowClicked"]], {
    cat("Run the function for row ", input[["rowClicked"]], "\n")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```